# What is needed for the inequality $c_1\cdot r^n \le f(r,n) \le c_2\cdot r^n$ to imply that $f(r,n)$ is of the form $c\cdot r^n$?

Tags: inequality

My conjuncture is that the key is that the inequality holds for abitrary small/big $r$, and therefore the difference between $$\frac{f(r,n)}{r^n}$$
and $c_1$ or $c_2$ is bounded.

I don't quite see though how to proceed from here.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? The inequalities cannot both be valid for $r=0.$ Or do you mean $\le?$

Comment: @gammatester Yes, you're correct. For $f$, I'd probably say $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $r,n\in\mathbb{R}$. Though I'd also be interested in any scenario where $r,n$ are elements of some metric space $M$ so that for $r_1,r_2\in M$ we have $\max(d_M(r_1,r_2)) = \infty$ , and $\min(d_M(r_1,r_2)) = -\infty$